# NoMethodError: undefined method `pluck' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

I am currently working with Ruby on Rails and I encountered a weird thing.

So, I am creating an array, then using `.pluck(:client_id)` on that array and I get the following error: `NoMethodError: undefined method 'pluck' for nil:NilClass`.

I used `binding.pry` to check if the array is indeed nil, but this is the result:

```
    49: def get_associations(records, tuples)
 => 50:   binding.pry
    51:   ClientAssociatedLocation.with_deleted.
    52:     where(client_id: records.pluck(:client_id)).
    53:     where("CONCAT_WS('-', client_id, location_id) IN (?)", tuples)
    54: end

[1] pry(#<AssociatedLocations::SourcesCreator>)> records
=> [{:id=>nil, :user_id=>nil, :client_id=>1523, :location_id=>2257, :association_type=>"manual"}]
[2] pry(#<AssociatedLocations::SourcesCreator>)> records.pluck(:client_id)
=> [1523]
[3] pry(#<AssociatedLocations::SourcesCreator>)>
```

As you can see, the records is clearly not nil and the pluck works. Do you have any idea of why this occurred?

Comment: Or without context, nope. If this is where the error actually is it’s `nil` at **some** point.

Comment: What is `records`, meaning where does it come from? Sidenote: If `records` is actually allowed to be `nil` at some point then I would assume this method should return an empty relation which could be done via `return ClientAssociatedLocation.none unless records`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this:

```rb
def get_associations(records, tuples)
  binding.pry
  ClientAssociatedLocation.with_deleted.
    where(client_id: records.pluck(:client_id)).
    where("CONCAT_WS('-', client_id, location_id) IN (?)", tuples)
end
```

To this:

```rb
def get_associations(records, tuples)
  binding.pry if records.nil?
  ClientAssociatedLocation.with_deleted.
    where(client_id: records.pluck(:client_id)).
    where("CONCAT_WS('-', client_id, location_id) IN (?)", tuples)
end
```

Then re-run the operation as many times as it takes to trigger the binding. The problem is that `records` is `nil` some of the time. You'll need to figure out the conditions that cause it by trapping only that issue.

Realistically, you should have the `binding.pry` call placed somewhere lower in the stack. Find wherever you call `get_associations(records, tuples)` and put in `binding.pry if records.nil?` *there* instead, so that you can see the context in which it's called.

You've tagged this question with both Ruby on Rails 3 *and* Ruby on Rails 4 so I assume you're using some very old versions of Ruby and Rails. If you weren't then I'd recommend using [debug](https://github.com/ruby/debug) over pry to make the debugging a little easier.